# Need to create new mongo database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot application with Spring-data-JPA and Mongo database.
Sometimes I discover an issue, below is my stack trace.

### Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:149) at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193) at java.lang.String.(String.java:426) at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder$BSONInput.readUTF8String(BasicBSONDecoder.java:552) at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:230) at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:154) at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:132) at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:62) at com.mongodb.Response.(Response.java:85) at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:141) at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:135) at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:164) at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:135) at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:289) at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:268) at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:234) at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.getMore(QueryResultIterator.java:137) at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.hasNext(QueryResultIterator.java:127) at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:551) at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1815) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1639) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1622) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:535) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$Execution.readCollection(AbstractMongoQuery.java:168) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$CollectionExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:191) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:103) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)

I used AWS instance to deploy my application, and my database also resides in the same instance.
And to resolve the same issue I need to create the new database.
Because of that my all old data wiped out.
so does there any solution for this.
Kindly provide me the solution.

Comment: which web server you are using

Comment: To prevent OutOfMemoryErrors: increase the memory

Comment: @Amit Singh we are using tomcat 8